# matlab bsxfun not multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, performance, matlab, bsxfun

I am using Matlab R2011a and according to the documentation the `bsxfun` function is multithreaded since R2009a (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/br5k34y-1.html). However when I use bsxfun to compare a matrix against an upper and lower bound like this:

```
szS=10000;
szT=50000;
matT=rand(szT,3);
matS=rand(szS,3);
matSub=rand(szS,3);
matSlb=rand(szS,3);
for k=1:szS
   matchID = all([bsxfun(@lt,matT,matSub(k,:)) bsxfun(@gt,matT,matSlb(k,:))],2);
end
```

on the task manager I see than only one core of is engaged. Am I missing out something or is this normal?

Comment: AFAIK the Task Manager only show processes not threads.. Also you should know that [multithreading](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN) only kicks in when the data is large enough

Comment: On another note, could you explain the variables in your code, and give us a minimum working example. Perhaps we can improve on it

Comment: On my 4-core 8-thread machine, when I do parfor I get a CPU Usage of (Nw/8) where Nw is the number of workers in put in my pool. But when I do bsxfun i get a solid %25. The target matrix (matT) has a dimension of (300K,3) which should be large enough I guess.

Comment: those are [not the same thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29#How_threads_differ_from_processes): `matlabpool` opens new sessions of MATLAB in the back, each in a separate process. And when you use `parfor` it distributes the load on all workers. `bsxfun` on the other hand executes the function in parallel (if it chooses to do so!) by launching lightweight threads inside the same process

Comment: Hmm, so does that mean that I would be better of if I switch to a 2-core/4-thread computer which has a higher CPU frequency?

Comment: they are not exclusive you know, you can mix both `parfor` and `bsxfun` in the same loop. Now the `parfor` approach really shines when you use it on a cluster of computers (ie: multiple machines running MATLAB workers, where you can distribute the work on all of them). Of course that requires the additional "Distributed Computing" Toolbox, but I doubt you'll need that much power..

Comment: I tried parforring the bsxfun but the process gets unstable and workers crash because it needs to transfer the matT matrix to all workers (I guess).

Comment: in theory, `parfor` only transfers what is needed to each worker. Once they are all done with the computation, it combines all the results into one. Anyways if you have a specific case, please write it in your question.

Comment: I've copied the relevant parts of my comments in a solution. This way the question has an actual answer...

Answer (score 2):

`bsxfun` executes the passed function in parallel by launching [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29) inside the same MATLAB process. Using only the "Task Manager" in Windows, you can't see the threads in execution, only running processes.

Just keep in mind that for the [supported multithreaded functions](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN), the speed up only applies if the data was large enough (but you are certainly above that threshold in you example).

Another option is with the *Parallel Computing Toolbox*. Using the `matlabpool` function, you can open new sessions of MATLAB in the back, each in a separate process. And when you call `parfor` it distributes the load on all workers. This approach scales very well especially when you run it on a cluster of computers.

I think it should be possible to use both in the same code..